# RemoteViewFactory onDataSetChange is called forever

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-widget, remoteview

I have a RemoteViewService in witch i get some data form firebase, the data is loaded correctly and displayed. But the problem is that onDataSetChanget() is called forever, and the data is loaded, and then reloaded and again, and again.I also tried to put the firebaseSnapShoatListener in oncreate and is working, but is has some problems.To be more clear - onDataSetChanged is called forever only when I call the method getData.Why is onDataSetChanget() called forever?

This is my code:

```
 public class TaskWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new TaskWidgetItemFactory(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }

    class TaskWidgetItemFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {
        private Context context;
        private int appWidgetId;
        private List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();

        private FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        private CollectionReference collectionReference = firestore.collection("Users")
                .document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .collection("Tasks");

        private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

        public TaskWidgetItemFactory(Context context, Intent intent) {
            this.context = context;
            this.appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            listenerRegistration = collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        //error
                    } else {
                        for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            int oldIndex = dc.getOldIndex();
                            int newIndex = dc.getNewIndex();
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = dc.getDocument();
                            Task task = documentSnapshot.toObject(Task.class);
                            switch (dc.getType()) {
                                case ADDED:
                                    taskList.add(newIndex, task);
                                    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.tasks_stack_view);
                                    break;
                                case REMOVED:
                                    taskList.remove(oldIndex);
                                    AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.tasks_stack_view);
                                    break;
                                case MODIFIED:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataSetChanged() {
            // getData();
        }

        private void getData() {
            listenerRegistration = collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        //error
                    } else {
                        for (DocumentChange dc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            int oldIndex = dc.getOldIndex();
                            int newIndex = dc.getNewIndex();
                            DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = dc.getDocument();
                            Task task = documentSnapshot.toObject(Task.class);
                            switch (dc.getType()) {
                                case ADDED:
                                    taskList.add(newIndex, task);
                                    break;
                                case REMOVED:
                                    taskList.remove(oldIndex);
                                    break;
                                case MODIFIED:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.tasks_stack_view);

                    }
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            listenerRegistration.remove();

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return taskList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_view_task_name, taskList.get(position).getName());
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_time_widget, taskList.get(position).getTime());
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_date_widget, taskList.get(position).getDate());
            return remoteViews;
        }

        @Override
        public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```